# Integrating $\int_0^{\infty}\log_2(1+q)\exp(-\beta q) \,\mathrm{d}q$

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, exponential-function, special-functions

I am trying to solve the following equation but not getting it correctly?

$$C = \int_0^{\infty}\log_2(1+q)\exp(-\beta q) \,\mathrm{d}q\tag{1}$$

where $\beta$ is constant and $q$ is integration variable.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated...

Comment: What have you tried? Is $\beta$ a positive real number?

Comment: Yes....$\beta$ is a positive real number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $\log_2(x)= \displaystyle\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}$.

Integrating by parts:

$$\int\ln(1+q)e^{-\beta q} \,\mathrm{d}q = -\frac{1}{\beta}\ln(1+q)e^{-\beta q} + \int \frac{1}{\beta} \frac{e^{-\beta q}}{1+ q} dq = \\
= -\frac{1}{\beta}\ln(1+q)e^{-\beta q} + e^{\beta}\int  \frac{e^{-\beta (1+q)}}{\beta(1+ q)} dq.$$

Using the integration extrema:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\ln(1+q)e^{-\beta q} \,\mathrm{d}q =
 \left[-\frac{1}{\beta}\ln(1+q)e^{-\beta q}\right]_{q=0}^{q=+\infty} + e^{\beta}\int_0^{+\infty}  \frac{e^{-\beta (1+q)}}{\beta(1+ q)} dq = \\
=
 [0-0] + e^{\beta}\int_0^{+\infty}  \frac{e^{-\beta (1+q)}}{\beta(1+ q)} dq.
$$

By substituting $s = \beta(1+q)$, we get:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}  \frac{e^{-\beta (1+q)}}{\beta(1+ q)} dq = \frac{1}{\beta}\int_{\beta}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-s}}{s}ds = -\frac{1}{\beta}\mathrm{Ei}(-\beta),$$

where $\mathrm{Ei}(\cdot)$ is known as [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Hence:

$$C =  -\displaystyle\frac{e^{\beta}}{\beta\ln(2)}\mathrm{Ei}(-\beta).$$

Unfortunately, since $\mathrm{Ei}$ cannot be explicitly computed (it is a special function). Then, numerical evaluation is required.

Comment: Thank you so much sir .....

Comment: Since $-\beta<0$, you should write $E_1(\beta)$ instead of $E_i(-\beta)$.

Comment: I prefer notations $\operatorname{Ei}(-\beta)$ and $\operatorname{Ei}_1(\beta)$

Comment: @GEdgar totally agree, corrected now, thanks a lot.

Comment: I prefer $\operatorname{Ei}$ not $Ei$.  Multi-letter names in roman type.  Such as $\sin \theta$ not $sin \theta$.

Comment: The closed form for the last integral should be $\int_\beta^\infty e^{-s}/s \, ds = -\operatorname {Ei}(-\beta)$ (for $\beta > 0$, $-\operatorname {Ei}(-\beta)$ is also equal to $E_1(\beta)$ or $\Gamma(0, \beta)$).

Comment: Thanks all. (Almost) All you suggestions have been used in the answer.